# How to find out what script code and/or plugin is rendering appearance and functionality within an element on the page?

Tags: javascript, plugins, frameworks, rendering, element

I've found a control on another webpage that I like. Assuming the site developers didn't build it from scratch, how do I determine what scripting framework and/or plugin they're using to transform and style it?

It's like a selection control of sorts in "bar form".
It's on the [realtor.com site here](http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Rancho-Santa-Fe_CA).

[image]

I've gotten the class names used for the parent container and its children, but searching for occurances of those in the javascript docs using Opera's dragonfly didn't yield any matches. How do I find out how this is being constructed???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way that I know of that will tell you which code did render which elements. However you can go by deduction here. First of all, is the code rendered on the server or the client? An easy way to know for sure would be to inspect the initial source of the page and check if the elements are already present. If they are, it would mean that they were rendered server-side or they already existed in the initial static document.

As far as I can tell, the search bar markup doesn't seem to be generated client-side.

However, behaviour is certainly added client-side. I went through the code and from what I can tell they seem to be using a library that's also used on http://www.move.com/

The scripts of interest would be:

http://static.move.com/getstatic/getfile.ashx?chl=rdc&typ=js&vr=7.2.0.2340&fls=core/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min,core/jquery/jquery.cookie.min,core/jquery/jquery.validate.min,core/jquery/jquery.json-1.3,core/jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange,core/legacy/legacy-move,core/legacy/movedialog.min,core/namespace,core/utils/underscore-min,core/utils/storage-util,core/movecore,core/cookie/cookies,core/tracking/edwtracking,core/tracking/clientevents,core/tracking/dwgtracking,core/tracking/omnituretracking,core/tracking/comscoretracking,map/hashmapping,core/utils/hash-util,core/utils/support,core/utils/captcha-util,s_code,seo/_seoparagraphs,core/ui/bootstrap

http://static.move.com/getstatic/getfile.ashx?chl=rdc&typ=js&vr=7.2.0.2340&fls=nopaindoubleload4v6,core/utils/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0,search/searchview/_topsearchview,geography/didyoumean/_didyoumean,modal/_modalview,search/_propertysearchcore,search/_partialviewcontainer,core/ui/bootstrappopovertooltip,core/utils/fb_connect_util,core/utils/rc4encrypt,registration/_registrationwidget,core/ui/slider,search/facets/_facetconcepta,geography/_predictivetext,core/ui/bootstraptabs,map/mapview/_mapview,map/map,search/listview/_resultscount,core/ui/bootstrap,search/featuredhomes/_featuredhomes,search/listview/_listviewsort,core/ui/_loadingindicator,search/listview/_listview,admedia/_admedia,search/listview/_resultsperpage,fcma/_fcma,propertydetail/_freemovingquotehandler,propertydetail/leadforms/_leadmodels,core/ui/datepickr,propertydetail/_movingcalculator,search/_trackpageview,search/_tracksearch,registration/_rdcmyitemswidget,admedia/_trackingpixel,instruments,pagetophat/_pagetophat,admedia/_admediamanagercore,breadcrumb/_breadcrumb,contentmanagement/_linkingmodule

They seem to be passing module names to the `getfile.ashx` page. You could probably eliminate the modules that seems useless for what you are looking for, which would make the code analysis easier.

Once you retrieved the sources, you can use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to format the code.

Have a look at everything namespaced in `MoveCore` and `MoveLib`. The library seems to be broken down by modules, where the page would register the modules it needs with `MoveCore.Tracking.addService`.

**Please note that I doubt it's actually legal to "steal" the code and I would strongly advise you to roll your own solution instead.**

Comment: Yes, thanks for the copyright notice. I was just trying to ascertain if they were using an open source javascript plugin of sorts that I could also leverage.

Comment: Good point with checking the initial page source to see if the final markup is the same.

Comment: I did see the references to move.com, but that's when it started getting more complex than I wanted to spend the time investigating and was wondering how the more seasoned web developers would tackle this.

Comment: @johntrepreneur Well it would probably take a good amount of effort for any developer to understand what's going on enough to reuse the code in another site and I doubt someone will take the time to do it for you, however you could always get lucky =P